# Java GUI Window Displays Garbage

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I wrote a Java program to take a triangle and either rotate, shift, or rotate and shift it, based upon a button click preformed by the user.

Beforehand, I instruct the user to enter in ranges of logical coordinates to determine how pixel coordinates will map to a real x-y coordinate system.

Initially, I have the triangle appearing in the middle of the screen, and after a button is clicked, the triangle is shown after a certain operation is preformed on it (i.e rotation, shifting, etc.)

However, after the operation is completed and the triangle is redrawn, I see an input box also drawn in the top-left corner of the JPanel.

I'm not sure how this keeps getting drawn there.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RotateAndShiftTriangles extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) { new RotateAndShiftTriangles(); }

   RotateAndShiftTriangles() {
       super("Drawing 50 Triangles");

       final JPanel drawingPanel = new DrawTriangles();
       JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
       JButton rotate = new JButton("Rotate"),
               shift = new JButton("Shift"),
               rotateShift = new JButton("Rotate and Shift"),
               reset = new JButton ("Reset");

       drawingPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

       buttonPanel.add(rotate);
       buttonPanel.add(shift);
       buttonPanel.add(rotateShift);
       buttonPanel.add(reset);

       addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
               System.exit(0);
           }
       });

       DrawTriangles.rWidth = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input rWidth"));
       DrawTriangles.rHeight = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input rHeight"));

       rotate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               DrawTriangles.rotate = true;
               drawingPanel.repaint();
           }
       });

       shift.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               DrawTriangles.shift = true;
               drawingPanel.repaint();
           }
       });

       rotateShift.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DrawTriangles.rotate = true;
                DrawTriangles.shift = true;
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            }
       });

       reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DrawTriangles.reset = true;
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            }
       });

       setSize(600, 400);
       add("South", buttonPanel);
       add("Center", drawingPanel);
       setVisible(true);
   }
}

class DrawTriangles extends JPanel {
    static float rWidth, rHeight, pixelSize;
    static int maxX, maxY, minMaxXY, centerX, centerY;
    static boolean rotate = false, shift = false, reset = false;
    float angle = 0;

    void initialize() {
        Dimension d = getSize();
        maxX = d.width - 1; maxY = d.height - 1;
        pixelSize = Math.max(rWidth / maxX, rHeight / maxY);
        minMaxXY = Math.min(maxX, maxY);
        centerX = maxX/2; centerY = maxY/2;
    }

    public int iX2(float x) { return Math.round(x); }
    public int iY2(float y) { return maxY - Math.round(y); }
    public static int iX(float x) { return Math.round(centerX + x / pixelSize); }
    public static int iY(float y) { return Math.round(centerY - y / pixelSize); }
    public static float fx(int x) { return (x - centerX) * pixelSize; }
    public static float fy(int y) { return (centerY - y) * pixelSize; }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        initialize();

        int left = iX(-rWidth/2), right = iX(rWidth/2);
        int top = iY(rHeight/2), bot = iY(-rHeight/2);

        g.drawString("X: " + -rWidth/2 + " Y: " + rHeight/2, left, top + 10);
        g.drawString("X: " + rWidth/2 + " Y: " + rHeight/2, right - 55, top + 10);
        g.drawString("X: " + -rWidth/2 + " Y: " + -rHeight/2, left, bot);
        g.drawString("X: " + rWidth/2 + " Y: " + -rHeight/2, right - 55, bot);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(left, top, right - left, bot - top);

        float side = 0.95f * minMaxXY, sideHalf = 0.5F * side,
                h = sideHalf * (float)Math.sqrt(3),
                xA, yA, xB, yB, xC, yC, 
                xA1, yA1, xB1, yB1, xC1, yC1, p, q;

        q = 0.05F;
        p = 1 - q;

        xA = centerX - sideHalf;
        yA = centerY - 0.5F * h;
        xB = centerX + sideHalf;

        yB = yA;

        xC = centerX;
        yC = centerY + 0.5F * h;

        if(!reset) {
            if(rotate) {
                angle += Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Angle of Rotation (in degrees)"));
                float xR = fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input X Coordinate for Rotation"))),
                        yR = fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Y Coordinate for Rotation")));

                xA = rotateX(xA, yA, xR, yR, angle);
                yA = rotateY(xA, yA, xR, yR, angle);

                xB = rotateX(xB, yB, xR, yR, angle);
                yB = rotateY(xB, yB, xR, yR, angle);

                xC = rotateX(xC, yC, xR, yR, angle);
                yC = rotateY(xC, yC, xR, yR, angle);

                rotate = false;
            }
            if(shift) {
                float xShift = -fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input X Coordinate for Shift"))),
                        yShift = -fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Y Coordinate for Shift")));

                xA += xShift; 
                yA += yShift;

                xB += xShift;
                yB += yShift;

                xC += xShift;
                yC += yShift;

                shift = false;
            }
        }

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            g.drawLine(iX2(xA), iY2(yA), iX2(xB), iY2(yB));
            g.drawLine(iX2(xB), iY2(yB), iX2(xC), iY2(yC));
            g.drawLine(iX2(xC), iY2(yC), iX2(xA), iY2(yA));

            if(i == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString("A: X- " + xA + " Y- " + yA, 0, 50);
                g.drawString("B: X- " + xB + " Y- " + yB, 0, 60);
                g.drawString("C: X- " + xC + " Y- " + yC, 0, 70);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            }

            xA1 = p * xA + q * xB;
            yA1 = p * yA + q * yB;
            xB1 = p * xB + q * xC;
            yB1 = p * yB + q * yC;
            xC1 = p * xC + q * xA;
            yC1 = p * yC + q * yA;

            xA = xA1; xB = xB1; xC = xC1;
            yA = yA1; yB = yB1; yC = yC1;
        }
        if(reset)
            angle = 0;
        reset = false;
    }

    public float rotateX(float x, float y, float xR, float yR, float angle) {
        angle *= (Math.PI / 180.0);
        float c = (float)Math.cos(angle), s = (float)Math.sin(angle),
                xF = x - xR, yF = y - yR,
                rx = xF * c - yF * s;

        return rx + xR;
    }

    public float rotateY(float x, float y, float xR, float yR, float angle) {
        angle *= (Math.PI / 180.0);
        float c = (float)Math.cos(angle), s = (float)Math.sin(angle),
                xF = x - xR, yF = y - yR,
                ry = xF * s + yF * c;

        return ry + yR;
    }
}
```

I keep getting this
[image: Java GUI Garbage]

Comment: I copied your code into my Eclipse editor.  The code abends when I input a  rWidth of 30, an rHeight of 30, and then click on the rotate button.  You rely way too much on static fields and JOptionPanels.  Recreate your program with an InputPanel, a DrawingPanel, and a ButtonPanel.  Don't use any static fields at all.

Comment: you forgot to mentioned that this code generating NPE and awfull exception from RepaintManager,

Comment: Why don't I want to use static fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are triggering `JOptionPane` popups *inside* your `paint()` method.

Calls to `.paint()` and its siblings should limit themselves to redrawing the object, nothing else.  As is, your code will cause your `.paint()` method to block until the popup is closed, then continue processing where it left off, potentially picking up artifacts still on the screen.  As you can see here, the background is painted (by the call to `super.paintComponent()`) then the popup is drawn and closed, then the rest of your `.paint()` method runs, but since the background has already been painted, nothing repaints over where the popup was.

You should move code like:

> ```
> angle += Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Angle of Rotation (in degrees)"));
> float xR = fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input X Coordinate for Rotation"))),
>       yR = fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Y Coordinate for Rotation")));
> ```

and

> ```
> float xShift = -fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input X Coordinate for Shift"))),
>       yShift = -fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Y Coordinate for Shift")));
> ```

out into the appropriate `ActionListener` methods, set the necessary values, and then use them from within your `paint()` method.

---

You should also be consistent about using `.paint()` and `.paintComponent()`, like @camickr suggests, don't have one method call its sibling's super.

Comment: 1+, yes, the showInputDialog is a big problem, never do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

Don't know if it is the only problem but, custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

Edit:

Other comments, not directly related to the problem, but important for proper design:

```
add("South", buttonPanel);
add("Center", drawingPanel);
```

Don't use hard coded literals. The layout manager will provide variable you can use. Also, that form of the add(...) method is not recommended (read the API). The new form is:

```
add(buttonPanel, BordeLayout.PAGE_END);
add("Center", BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Don't use static methods and variables. If you want to change a property of your class then create "setter" method. For example create a setter method:

```
public void setRotate(Boolean rotate)
{
    this.rotate = rotate
    repaint();
}
```

Also, not that the setter method invokes the repaint() method. This is because your custom class (not the code that uses the class) should be responsible for doing the repaint.

Then invoke the setter method:

```
//DrawTriangles.rotate = true; // wrong
drawingPanel.setRotate(true);
```

Comment: I tried replacing `paint(Graphics g)` with `paintComponent(Graphics g)` but am still getting the same result :/

Comment: Why would I choose to use setter methods instead of static methods or variables? I don't see why there's a downside in design from using static variables.

Comment: @Delfino, it is a terrible approach and does not support the concept of reusable code. No other Swing components are designed like this. For example what if you want to add two DrawTriangle classes to your frame. It wouldn't work. I already gave you another reason, which I will rephrase slightly, `every component should be responsible for repainting itself when a property of the class changes.`. You usage of static is completely wrong, just because it happens to work is not a reason to continue using it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this only happens if dialogs are displayed. I've modified the code and hardcoded some values, it worked without problems.

```
if(!reset) {
        if(rotate) {
            angle += Float.parseFloat("15");
            float xR = fx(3),
                    yR = fx(3);
            // other stuff...
        }
```

I suggest you try displaying dialogs and setting corresponding values **before** repainting the components, something similar to this:

```
       shift.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           float xShift = -DrawTriangles.fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input X Coordinate for Shift"))),
                   yShift = -DrawTriangles.fx(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Y Coordinate for Shift")));
           drawingPanel.xShift = xShift;
           drawingPanel.yShift = yShift;
           DrawTriangles.shift = true;
           drawingPanel.repaint();
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BufferedImage corrected the drawing but still the exception occurred.

```
public void paint(Graphics gg) {
    BufferedImage bf = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g = bf.createGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

...

    gg.drawImage(bf, 0, 0, null);

    if(reset)
        angle = 0;
    reset = false;
}
```